# Data.table efficient creating of list columns and unspanning

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table

I have a large data table which has a date_start and a date_end column for a number of individuals. About a third of these are already individual-month level, that is date_start and date_end are the same date. I'd like to convert the two thirds into individual-month level observations as well.

For example:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

person<-1:10
date_start<-seq(ymd("20200101"),ymd("20201001"),"1 month")
date_end<-seq(ymd("20210101"),ymd("20211001"),"1 month")
dt<-data.table(person,date_start,date_end)

df1<-dt%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(dates_list = list(seq(date_start, date_end, by = "1 month")))%>%
  as.data.table()

df1%>%
  unnest(dates_list)%>%
  as.data.table()
```

Is there a faster way to do this over a large data table / is there a way to do this with {data.table}. Additionally I'm on a server with 40 cores, so I can brute force it via {parallel} if there are solutions there.

Comment: It would be a little better to use examples not having a huge number of dependencies just to do something simple.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, I probably could've cut {tidyverse}, but as a primarily R-user my default is to load it in always. Asking questions is a skill I'm still honing, so I'll keep this in mind in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a very straight-forward way is close to what you have, using `Map` instead of row-wise:

```r
dt[, .(dates_list = do.call(c, Map(seq.Date, date_start, date_end, by = "1 month"))),
   by = c("person", "date_start", "date_end")]
#      person date_start   date_end dates_list
#       <int>     <Date>     <Date>     <Date>
#   1:      1 2020-01-01 2021-01-01 2020-01-01
#   2:      1 2020-01-01 2021-01-01 2020-02-01
#   3:      1 2020-01-01 2021-01-01 2020-03-01
#   4:      1 2020-01-01 2021-01-01 2020-04-01
#   5:      1 2020-01-01 2021-01-01 2020-05-01
#   6:      1 2020-01-01 2021-01-01 2020-06-01
#   7:      1 2020-01-01 2021-01-01 2020-07-01
#   8:      1 2020-01-01 2021-01-01 2020-08-01
#   9:      1 2020-01-01 2021-01-01 2020-09-01
#  10:      1 2020-01-01 2021-01-01 2020-10-01
#  ---                                        
# 121:     10 2020-10-01 2021-10-01 2021-01-01
# 122:     10 2020-10-01 2021-10-01 2021-02-01
# 123:     10 2020-10-01 2021-10-01 2021-03-01
# 124:     10 2020-10-01 2021-10-01 2021-04-01
# 125:     10 2020-10-01 2021-10-01 2021-05-01
# 126:     10 2020-10-01 2021-10-01 2021-06-01
# 127:     10 2020-10-01 2021-10-01 2021-07-01
# 128:     10 2020-10-01 2021-10-01 2021-08-01
# 129:     10 2020-10-01 2021-10-01 2021-09-01
# 130:     10 2020-10-01 2021-10-01 2021-10-01
```

This performs fairly well, though we have some hard-coded column names (not sure if that's a problem). Notes:

- `Map(...)` is similar to your `rowwise` and `list` portion
- `do.call(c, ...)` is similar to `unlist`, but the latter removes the `"Date"` class

This is also a bit faster with this smaller 10-row `dt`.

```r
bench::mark(
  data.table = dt[, .(dates_list = do.call(c, Map(seq.Date, date_start, date_end, by = "1 month"))), 
                  by = c("person", "date_start", "date_end")],
  dplyr = dt %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(dates_list = list(seq(date_start, date_end, by = "1 month"))) %>%
    unnest(dates_list) %>%
    as.data.table()
)
# # A tibble: 2 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result         memory               time             gc                
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>         <list>               <list>           <list>            
# 1 data.table  955.2µs   1.03ms      968.    48.2KB     2.91   333     1      344ms <dt [130 × 4]> <Rprofmem [143 × 3]> <bench_tm [334]> <tibble [334 × 3]>
# 2 dplyr        4.87ms   5.11ms      195.      41KB     0       98     0      503ms <dt [130 × 4]> <Rprofmem [495 × 3]> <bench_tm [98]>  <tibble [98 × 3]>
```

and the results are the same:

```r
all.equal(
  dt[, .(dates_list = do.call(c, Map(seq.Date, date_start, date_end, by = "1 month"))),
     by = c("person", "date_start", "date_end")],
  dt %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(dates_list = list(seq(date_start, date_end, by = "1 month"))) %>%
    unnest(dates_list) %>%
    as.data.table(),
  check.attributes = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you use `do.call()` and `Map` here.  Why not simply  `dt[, .(date_start, date_end, dates_list = seq(date_start, date_end, by="1 month")), person]`?

Comment: @langtang (1) `Map` because "old habits", I didn't assume that it's perfectly one-row-per-person; (2) `do.call` because it was an alternative to `tidyr::unnest`, in case the OP wanted a data.table-only solution.